# Overriding Panning functionality in JGraphX using java

Tags: java, jgraphx

I am using JGraphX to implement "Panning" functionality. 
I have used graphcomponent.setPanning(true) and is working perfectly if I do  Ctrl+Shift + left mouse click and drag as required.

But I have to simplify this functionality. Say Alt+ Left mouse click should enable panning.

Going further, I want to provide a button to the user such that panning should be enabled when user clicks on the button , Of course using mouse and any keyboard key combination.
And user clicks on the same button to exit panning mode.

Any solutions/directions is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override mxGraphComponnet.isPanningEvent